# variables in the flash scope don't stay alive in Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, playframework

When a user tries to access a page in the administration controllers (mostly CRUD stuff), he is being redirected to the login page. And, if the credentials is correct and he is indeed an administrator, he is begin redirected to the page he wanted to access in the previous request.

Whenever someone tries to access a forbidden page he is being redirected to the following controller:

```
    public static void login(String returnUrl) throws Throwable {
    Http.Cookie remember = request.cookies.get("rememberme");
    flash.put("url",returnUrl);
    if (remember != null && remember.value.indexOf("-") > 0) {
        String sign = remember.value.substring(0, remember.value.indexOf("-"));
        String username = remember.value.substring(remember.value.indexOf("-") + 1);
        if (Crypto.sign(username).equals(sign)) {
            session.put("username", username);
            redirectToOriginalURL(returnUrl);
        }
    }
    flash.keep();
    render();
}
```

Which executes the authenticte(...) method:

```
public static void authenticate(@Required String username, String password, boolean remember, String returnUrl) throws Throwable {
    // Check tokens
    Boolean allowed = false;
    // This is the official method name
    allowed = (Boolean) Security.invoke("authenticate", username, password);
    if (validation.hasErrors() || !allowed) {
        flash.keep("url");
        flash.error("secure.error");
        params.flash();
        login(returnUrl);
    }
    // Mark user as connected
    session.put("username", username);
    // Remember if needed
    if (remember) {
        response.setCookie("rememberme", Crypto.sign(username) + "-" + username, "30d");
    }
    // Redirect to the original URL (or /)
    flash.keep("url");
    redirectToOriginalURL(returnUrl);
}
```

Note the `String returnUrl` in the parameter list. This controller is always called in the view with the `response.url` value.

The redirectToOriginalURL() is a method that receives a returnUrl in the parameter or in the flash scope.

```
static void redirectToOriginalURL(String returnUrl) throws Throwable {
    if(returnUrl==null) returnUrl = flash.get("url");
    if (returnUrl == null) {
        returnUrl = "/";
    }
    redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer. But when I try to execute this in Google Chrome, the returnUrl is `null`. Is this a known issue, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

There are no special requests or anything. The url, when redirected from the unaccessible page (`localhost:9000/admin`) is `http://localhost:9000/account?returnUrl=%2Fadmin`. So nothing wrong there...

The error must therefore lie withing the authenticate controller, that seems to be unable to pass arguments to the redirectToOriginalURL method. But, then again, only in Google Chrome.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working this way:

Make sure that checkAccess method calls login method with current url:

```
static void checkAccess() throws Throwable {
    // Authent
    if (!session.contains("username")) {            
        login(request.method.equals("GET") ? request.url : "/");
    }
}
```

Then in login.html view add the hidden field which is the param you already passed to login method:

```
#{form @authenticate()}
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="${params.returnUrl}">
...
#{/form}
```

Or add returnUrl param directly to form.action:

```
#{form @authenticate().add("returnUrl", params.returnUrl)}
```

That's it. And you don't need flash scope.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks!
Is there a way of collecting the parameters in the query string from the controller? Because if you have to put a hidden field in your view, every time you want to redirect... That's hard to maintain :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, use this: #{form @authenticate().add("returnUrl", params.returnUrl)}

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this line of code in login:

```
 redirectToOriginalURL();
```

That calling the method with no arguments, but the redirectToOriginalURL you show has a parameter String. Could it be this is part of the issue?

Comment: That's an artefact from the copy-pasting... there should be returnUrl in the parameter of course. Thanks for pointing that out!